# ListView fling performance worse on Galaxy 10.1" Tab (3.1) vs 7" Tab (2.2)

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I have a simple ListView which contains a number of TextViews.

When I do a (similar) fling through this list, on a Galaxy Tab 10.1" and a Galaxy Tab 7", I notice the following differences:

- the fling duration is much shorter on the 10.1" (about 2.6 sec vs 1.7 sec)
- the fling distance is much more on the 10.1" (the list scrolled more)
- the number of calls to OnScrollListener.onScroll is much lower on the 10.1" (probably linked to the smaller duration)

All in all, this results a worse performance (less repaints/items-scrolled)

Any suggestions on how to improve this?
Eg. can we control (extend) the duration of the fling?

I add the example code illustrating this behavior below

```
public class TestSwipe extends Activity
{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ListView t = new ListView(this);
  t.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);        
  t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  t.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter()
  {

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
      {
          TextView t = new TextView(TestSwipe.this);
          t.setText("TV: "+position);
          return t;
      }

      public long getItemId(int position)
      {
          return 0;
      }

      public Object getItem(int position)
      {
          return null;
      }

      public int getCount()
      {
          return 10000;
      }
  });

  t.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
  {
    int ctr=0;
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
    {
        Log.d("TWINTV", "scrollState="+scrollState);
        ctr=0;
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        Log.d("TWINTV", "onScroll="+ctr++);

    }
  });
  setContentView(t);
}

}
```